# Supress welcome banner only in SCP

Tags: scp, banner

I am creating the file copy tool using python across the nodes as passwordless.

While doing that, I encountered a banner message output also in `scp` command along with a progress bar. I want to suppress the banner message and show only the progress bar.

The command used:

```
scp -q <file_name> username@server:path
```

Answer (score 0):

The -q option should do the trick. The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) specify the `q` option to be used for the use cases.

> -q' Quiet mode: disables the progress meter as well as warning and diagnostic messages from ssh(1).

Can you share the exact command/code and the output which you are getting?

Comment: As said earlier, "-q" supress both welcome message and progress meter. I want supress welcome banner and show only progress meter.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the output by raising the error level of the underlying ssh connection. (Credis: [bash: how to suppress login message from scp output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597684/bash-how-to-suppress-login-message-from-scp-output))

```
scp -o LogLevel=Error "$src" "root@$h:$dest"
```