# bash: how to suppress login message from scp output

Tags: bash, openssh

I have a simple bash function for interactive use:

```
push-file() {
     hosts="$1"
     src="$2"
     dest="$3"
     for h in "$hosts"
     do
        echo "=== $h ==="
        scp "$src" root@$h:"$dest"
     done
}
```

I can then type, for example:

```
push-file "host1 host2" testfile /tmp/
```

to copy `testfile` to both of the hosts.  (In reality in place of the `"host1 host2"` I might use a variable e.g. `"$foo_hosts"` to specify a certain group of hosts.)

However, there is a complication: on each of the hosts, there are 10 lines of boilerplate AUP message displayed whenever you ssh to them, so the output looks like:

```
=== host1 ===
   Access to this system is monitored [etc...]
   [9 more lines of AUP]
testfile                                           100%  188    11.2KB/s   00:00
=== host2 ===
   Access to this system is monitored [etc...]
   [9 more lines of AUP]
testfile                                           100%  188    11.6KB/s   00:00
```

But I want it to look like:

```
=== host1 ===
testfile                                           100%  188    11.2KB/s   00:00
=== host2 ===
testfile                                           100%  188    11.6KB/s   00:00
```

(Here, the final line from `scp` is a progress meter -- you are seeing it here as it appears on the terminal after completion of the transfer.)

Now, the AUP message is always 10 lines long, so it should just be a case of removing the first 10 lines, but there are further complicating factors:

- The AUP message is written by `scp` to stderr.  This will need to be piped to the `tail -n 11`.  I cannot afford to just direct stderr to `/dev/null`, as error messages after the AUP message may be lost.
- The progress meter is written to stdout by `scp`, but it seemingly is only written if stdout is a terminal.  Any tricks involving `&>` which allow stderr to be piped also seem to cause the stdout of the `scp` process to be a pipe rather than a terminal, and then the progress meter is suppressed.

The best I could come up with was to replace:

```
     scp "$src" root@$h:"$dest"
```

with:

```
     { script -q -c "scp \"$src\" root@$h:\"$dest\" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3" /dev/null | tail -n +11; } 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

which works, but is hideous.

**QUESTION** - Is there anything simpler and cleaner?

Here's the OpenSSH version, in case there is a way to modify the scp behaviour directly rather than postprocessing the output in bash: `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`

Comment: @chepner Yes exactly.

Comment: Add `-q` to `scp`?

Comment: @Cyrus `-q` disables the progress meter as well.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the askubuntu link, but I'm probably not at liberty to mess with the login banner on the server side.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mean to post a link to one of the answers to that question, which suggests setting the client-side logging level to Error. https://askubuntu.com/a/703230.

Comment: @chepner Yes, that's done it, many thanks. Do you want to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (apparently) suppress the output by raising the error level of the underlying `ssh` connection. (Credit to https://askubuntu.com/a/703230.)

```
scp -o LogLevel=Error "$src" "root@$h:$dest"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this. In fact, this option is now going into my client-side `~/.ssh/config` and I don't even need to modify the command line :-)

Comment: Awesome. It worked exactly as I intended to do. Thanks a lot.